# In C, I'm unable to copy a single element of an array of character strings to another string

Tags: c, token, strcpy, strncpy

I have a string "prompt" that holds a string of characters. The user must be able to change the prompt with user input, which I've collected and separated (using whitespace as a delimiter) into an array of `char` strings (tokens).

For example, assume:

```
char **tokens[2] = {"setprompt", "newprompt"};
char *prompt = "oldprompt";

if(strcmp(tokens[0], "setprompt") == 0)
{
strcpy(prompt, tokens[1]);
}
```

The `strcmp()` function works perfectly fine, however when it reaches `strcpy()`, the element in `tokens[1]` (which is the string `"newprompt"`) isn't copied into the string prompt. This is my problem.

I've tried troubleshooting, in addition to using `strncpy()` instead but I think there's an issue somewhere with my declarations of each variable/pointer. Any assistance or ideas would be great.

Note: in my actual program, the tokens array doesn't have a definitive size of 2. This example is modified for simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.  `char **tokens[2] = {"setprompt", "newprompt"};` --> "warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type".

Comment: `char **tokens[2] = ...` --> `char *tokens[2] = ...`  One too many `*`.  [@Michael Dorgan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47297880/2410359) has a good lead on another problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is this line:

```
char *prompt = "oldprompt";
```

It points to constant memory and cannot be modified (the way it is defined).  Consider leaving it read-only and creating your own buffer instead for copying and modifying  Something like:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 255

char *tokens[2] = {"setprompt", "newprompt"};
char *prompt = "oldprompt";
char myBuffer[MAX_STRING_SIZE];

strcpy(myBuffer, prompt );

if(strcmp(tokens[0], "setprompt") == 0)
{
    strcpy(myBuffer, tokens[1]);
}
```

Comment: Lots of ways to skin this cat.  I went with something very simple and easy to understand to start.  I'm surprised that he wasn't getting some kind of run-time error about the copy causing a crash.

Comment: `char **tokens[2] = {"setprompt", "newprompt"};` See [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297861/in-c-im-unable-to-copy-a-single-element-of-an-array-of-character-strings-to-an#comment81548105_47297861).  This is poor code.

Comment: yeah, nice catch.

Comment: Difference between *array of pointer to pointer to char [2]* and *array of pointer to char [2]*.